# Kotlin coroutine doesn't wait to be done

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a legacy project where I want to use coroutines when contacting the backend. The backend have been handle by a sdk delivered by Hybris. It use volley for instance, and with some callbacks. What I want is to wrap those callbacks with a coroutine. But the problem I have is that the coroutine doesn't wait to be done, it start the coroutine, and keep going to next lines, and method returns a value, and long after that the coroutine finish. 
My code:

```
suspend  fun ServiceHelper.getList(): ListOfWishes {

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        getAllLists(object : ResponseReceiver<ListOfWishes> {
            override fun onResponse(response: Response<ListOfWishes>?) {
                continuation.resume(response?.data!!)

            }

            override fun onError(response: Response<ErrorList>?) {
                val throwable = Throwable(Util.getFirstErrorSafe(response?.data))
                continuation.resumeWithException(throwable)
            }
        }, RequestUtils.generateUniqueRequestId(), false, null, object : OnRequestListener {
            override fun beforeRequest() {}
            override fun afterRequestBeforeResponse() {}
            override fun afterRequest(isDataSynced: Boolean) {}
        })
    }
}
```

The helper method:

```
suspend fun ServiceHelper.wishLists(): Deferred<ListOfWishes> {
    return async(CommonPool) {
        getWishList()
    }
}
```

And where the coroutine is called:

```
    fun getUpdatedLists(): ListOfWishes? {
    val context = Injector.getContext()
    val serviceHelper = Util.getContentServiceHelper(context) 
    var list = ListOfWishLists()
    launch(Android) {
        try {
            list = serviceHelper.wishLists().await()
        } catch (ex: Exception){
            Timber.d("Error: $ex")
        }
    }
    return list
```

So instead of waiting for `serviceHelper.wishLists().await()` is done, it return list. I have also tried to make the method return a `runBlocking{}`, but that only block the UI thread and doesn't end the coroutine.

Comment: If you replace `launch(Android)` with `runBlocking`, this should not create a new coroutine that waits for `wishLists` to finish in background but wait in the current thread (possibly the UI thread) and return the actual list

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines don't work like this. `getUpdatedLists()` method can't wait a coroutine to finish its execution without being a `suspend` method itself. If method `getUpdatedLists()` defined in `Activity` or `Fragment`, you can launch a coroutine and do something, e.g. update UI, in it after `serviceHelper.wishLists().await()` is executed. It will look something like this:

```
fun loadUpdatedLists() {
    val context = Injector.getContext()
    val serviceHelper = Util.getContentServiceHelper(context) 
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        try {
            val list = serviceHelper.wishLists().await()
            // use list object, for example Update UI 
        } catch (ex: Exception){
            Timber.d("Error: $ex")
        }
    }
}
```

[`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) - `CoroutineScope` tied to `LifecycleOwner`'s `Lifecycle`. To use it add dependency:

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0 or higher.
```